# How to cite a ref without author name using elsarticle-harv style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, elsarticle, harvard-style

Prepare a ref for journal using elsarticle-harv style in overleaf.

However, for a program/software, there is not specific author for that software. All I want to cite is software name, html, date accessed. But if I left author = {} as blank, then elsarticle-harv style will give me something weird like

, . software name, html, date.

How can I get rid of the ,. at the begining? I also get warning for not have author. Just put in the software name does not help becuase it will still has the ,.

software name,. software name .....

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style generates harvard-style citation call-outs, also known as authoryear-style citation call-outs. So there's you source of the problem: One *cannot* create decent author-year type citation call-outs for entries that lack an `author` field. (What you've also discovered is that, in such cases, `elsarticle-harv` uses the `title` field as a fallback for `author`; however, that's often not satisfactory.) The solution is surprisingly simple: *Create your own luck*, by adding a suitably-worded `author` field to the entries in question.

Comment: R software suggest this bibtex entry:  `@Manual{,
    title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
    author = {{R Core Team}}, ....`  probably you can refer to the developers of your software in a similar way.